# Problem while runing powershell script by task schedular

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have one powershell script that is fully working.
But I want to schedule a task in Task scheduler to run it automatically.
But it does nothing at that Trigger time.

PS version is 5.1.17763.1490
OS is windows 10
Execution Policy details are as below.

```
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine          Bypass
```

Comment: Can you add the Action and argument(s) you've set in the task?  Also of concern is what account you've set it to run under, and what privileges you have or have not granted.

Comment: Agreed, can we get some code on how youre using it?

Comment: It worked for me by passing -File "C:\Users\529817\New folder\ARC_SCRIPT.ps1" in arguments tab. previously it didnt work because i had passed  "C:\Users\529817\New folder\ARC_SCRIPT.ps1" in the arguments tab.